# can't pass the list json param correctly

Tags: java

I want to use OKHttp3-based RestTemplate to remotely call the interface `queryByIds` to get basic user information.

```
@Configuration
public class CloudConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate(new OkHttp3ClientHttpRequestFactory());
    }
}
```

the implementing method `queryByIds` is below:

```
    @GetMapping("/queryByIds")
    public GraceJSONResult queryByIds(@RequestParam String userIds) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(userIds)) {
            return GraceJSONResult.errorCustom(ResponseStatusEnum.USER_NOT_EXIST_ERROR);
        }
        List<String> userIdList = JsonUtils.jsonToList(userIds, String.class);
        ArrayList<AppUserVO> userVOList = new ArrayList<>();
        assert userIdList != null;
        userIdList.forEach(id -> {
            AppUserVO userInfo = getBasicUserInfo(id);
            userVOList.add(userInfo);
        });
        return GraceJSONResult.ok(userVOList);
    }
```

Here is the bussiness code, the `http://user.mootalk.com` is switched to `localhost` using SwitchHosts:

```
        // Get the basic information of each user and put it in userVOList
        String userServerUrlExecute = "http://user.mootalk.com:8003/user/queryByIds?userIds=" + JsonUtils.objectToJson(publisherIdSet);

        System.out.println(userServerUrlExecute);

        // the debugger paused
        ResponseEntity<GraceJSONResult> entity =
                restTemplate.getForEntity(userServerUrlExecute, GraceJSONResult.class);
```

Here is my util class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * json converter
 */
public class JsonUtils {
    
    private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
    
    
    public static String objectToJson(Object data) {
        try {
            String string = MAPPER.writeValueAsString(data);
            return string;
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    
    public static <T> T jsonToPojo(String jsonData, Class<T> beanType) {
        try {
            T t = MAPPER.readValue(jsonData, beanType);
            return t;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    
    public static <T> List<T> jsonToList(String jsonData, Class<T> beanType) {
        JavaType javaType = MAPPER.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(List.class, beanType);
        try {
            List<T> list = MAPPER.readValue(jsonData, javaType);
            return list;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return null;
    }
    
}
```

When I debug the code ,it didn't go into the `queryByIds` method, and the console printed the `userServerUrlExecute` below:
[image]

But if you construct a request in Postman like this:
`http://user.mootalk.com:8003/user/queryByIds?userIds=210726G71HSY2YY8`, it could go into the `queryByIds` method but the `userIdList` turned out to be null.

If you construct a request in Postman like this :
`http://user.mootalk.com:8003/user/queryByIds?userIds=[\"210726G71HSY2YY8\",\"200628AFYM7AGWPH\"]`,it works well.

So what's wrong with my code while passing the param?

---

Later message1:

1. Now the last construct request did't go into `queryByIds` both in Chrome's address bar and Postman, it threw a `400 Bad Request`;
2. I replaced `@RequestParam` with `@RequestBody` in `queryByIds`, it still threw a `400 Bad Request`

---

Latter message2:

1. Now it works...with the same code. This is really a mystery.
   [image]

Comment: What you probably want to do is encode it to `base64` and pass that into `userIds` and than decode on the other side.

Comment: As @Popeye said, the problem is you need to encode your JSON if you are using it as a url param value. Still, I'd say passing JSON as a GET parameter is kind of nasty. To both solve your problem and make your API a bit easier to understand, I'd pass the JSON data in the request body

Comment: @m-alorda is correct, just because you can doesn't mean you should. Something else to consider if you want to pass into the URL I would probably consider doing it as a comma separated list instead of JSON. Ask yourself the question are you gaining anything by it being JSON if it's just a list of IDs? Why can't you just do `?userIds=210726G71HSY2YY8,200628AFYM7AGWPH`? From looking at your code you gain nothing by it being JSON.

Comment: @Popeye that's also a possibility, just throw the multiple values into the param value without JSON. Still, to let spring handle that, I'd suggest using a URI as such: `?userIds=XXXXX&userIds=YYYYY`

Comment: @m-alorda , later I used your method , and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Really I wouldn't just pass in JSON into a query parameter like you are doing, it's nasty and doesn't really follow any sort of RESTFUL API standard.

You have 4 options as I see it:

1. Change to a HTTP POST request and pass in the JSON Data into the request body (Recommend and follows best practise).
2. If for whatever reasons your requirements are it needs to be a HTTP GET request and needs to be a query parameter then you need to base64 encode the JSON before passing it in.

`?userIds=W1wiMjEwNzI2RzcxSFNZMllZOFwiLFwiMjAwNjI4QUZZTTdBR1dQSFwiXQ==`

3. Again if it has to be a HTTP GET request but it doesn't need to be JSON then I would do a comma separated list of IDs into the query parameter

`?userIds=210726G71HSY2YY8,200628AFYM7AGWPH`

4. Just request 1 user id at a time.

Your requirements are probably going to be what determines the approach you take.